# Remove text that starts with

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got a dynamically generated text, and i need to remove text that starts with dash.
The text is usually a one word, and I don't need to remove the whole word. Google is quite as well as search here. How can i do that?

let's say there is this piece of code with h3 text generated automatically

```
<h3>Startoftext-needtoremove</h3>
```

And i need to remove "-needtoremove"

With answer of ianaya89 I've tried doing this

```
$(".colsborder h3").each(function(){
   removeDash(str){
    if (str.substring(0, 1) === '-') {
      return str.replace('-', '');
    }
   }
  console.log(removeDash('-value')); 
});
```

Comment: u dont want to remove the whole word? so you only want to remove the dash?

Comment: Take a look at RegEx

Comment: i need to remove dash and whatever comes after it.

Comment: I'm confused. 1 word but you don't need to remove the whole word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to replace from the first `-` character and any characters there after.

```js
$(".colsborder h3").each(function(){
  var str = $(this).text();
  var replaced = str.replace(/-.*/, '');
  $(this).text(replaced)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="colsborder">
  <h3>Startoftext-needtoremove</h3>
</div>
```

This method would be faster than using the `substring` or `split` methods.

Comment: Yet the text is still there